# Disk "Volume Extend" command gives Error with Diskpart [WIndows 10]

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

On trying to extend a volume (N:) on a local disk (basic), the extend option is greyed out eventhough there is free space to its immediate right.

On using `diskpart` to extend this volume, the console gives the below error (script + error).

How to extend the disk volume in this case?

[image: disk]

*** Script + Error  ***

```
 DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          298 GB    70 GB
  Disk 1    No Media           0 B      0 B   


DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            549 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary            117 GB   550 MB
  Partition 3    Primary             30 GB   118 GB
  Partition 0    Extended           147 GB   148 GB
  Partition 4    Logical             77 GB   218 GB  

DISKPART> select partition 3

Partition 3 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> extend [size = 69,632] [disk = 0]

The arguments specified for this command are not valid.
For more information on the command type: HELP EXTEND  

DISKPART> SELECT VOLUME 3

Volume 3 is the selected volume.

DISKPART>  EXTEND SIZE=69,632

The arguments specified for this command are not valid.
For more information on the command type: HELP EXTEND
```

Comment: It's greyed out because that free space is a part of extended partition or in other words can only be used to increase size of extended partition and not the primary ones. If you have access to any linux (installed/live) then use gparted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the free space unallocated space first.

Create a new NTFS volume on the free space and then delete the newly created partition. Now you will get unallocated space.

Or you can also try shrinking space from an existing partition.

I would like to leave the crappy Microsoft disk management utility, and therefore use EaseUS partition manager or MinTool partition wizard.

Comment: Creating new NTFS volume by deleting free space didn't work. Had to use Minitool.